# Execution of Test scripts with Coded UI Test consumes more time

Tags: coded-ui-tests

We are facing few issues while executing Coded UI Test scripts.

Regulary we have to execute automated scripts on Coded UI Test, earlier we used Test Partner for execution. Recently we migrated few of our Test Partner scripts to Coded UI Test . However, we observed that Coded UI Test scripts execution time is more when compared toTest Partner exection time. Our automated scripts were completely hand written, no where we used recording and playback feature.

And few of our observations were

1. IE Browser hangs on executing Coded UI Test scripts on windows XP. Everytime we have to kill the process and we have to recreated the scenario to continue the execution further. So, it does not suffice the automation essentiality, as each and every time one has to monitor whether script execution goes fine without browser hang. Its a very frequent problem on XP.
2. If we execute Coded UI Test scripts on windows 7. The execution time is quite slow. It will consume more time then the execution time on XP. So our execution time drags, though script goes fine without Browser hang. We tried to execute scripts in release mode as well. But whenever script halts one has to execute script again in debug mode.

Could you please suggest on this. What exactly the point we are missing? By chaning tool settings can we improve performance of the execution time? Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should enable the logging and see why the search takes up so many time.
You can also find useful information in the debug outputs that give warning when operations take more time than expected.

Here are two useful links for enabling those logs

For VS/MTM 2010 and 2012 beta: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2009/11/29/how-to-enable-tracing-for-ui-test-components.aspx

For VS/MTM 2012 : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/06/05/enabling-coded-ui-test-playback-logs-in-visual-studio-2012-release-candidate.aspx

A friendly .html file with logs should be created in %temp%\UITestLogs*\LastRun\ directory.

As for the possible explanation to your issue - it doesn't matter if you coded your tests explicitly or by hand the produced calls to WpfControl.Find() or one of deriving classes, if the search fails at first it will move up to performing heuristics to find the targeted control anyway.

You can turn MatchExactHierachy setting of your Playback to be true, and stop using the smartmatch feature
(more on it here together with afew other usefull performance tips
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/08/10/configuring-playback-in-vstt-2010.aspx)